# Can't Get Post Images to Center

Tags: wordpress

I am working on this website: https://www.thewellnessproject.net/how-you-eat-is-how-you-live-the-7-types-of-eaters/

```html
<div class="wp-block-image"><figure class="aligncenter size-large is-resized"><img src="https://www.thewellnessproject.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/eat-how-you-live-PT-683x1024.png" alt="" class="wp-image-3048" width="550" srcset="https://www.thewellnessproject.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/eat-how-you-live-PT-683x1024.png 683w, https://www.thewellnessproject.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/eat-how-you-live-PT-200x300.png 200w, https://www.thewellnessproject.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/eat-how-you-live-PT-768x1152.png 768w, https://www.thewellnessproject.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/eat-how-you-live-PT-585x878.png 585w, https://www.thewellnessproject.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/eat-how-you-live-PT.png 900w" sizes="(max-width: 683px) 100vw, 683px" /></figure></div>
```

As you can see, the post image (about a quarter of the way down the page) will not center. I have the image set to center from the write-post page. I also went in and added code, such as the following:

```css
.post-content img {
 margin-top: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
.wp-block-image {
 text-align: center !important;
}
```

```css
.aligncenter {
 text-align: center !important;
}
```

Nothing seems to be working. Would really appreciate any input. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
.aligncenter {
    text-align: center;
    display: block !important;
}
```

You have `display: table;` on the `.aligncenter` class which you need to remove or override.